# How to make sure Facebook knows that you're a publisher, not a brand?

Tags: facebook

The past couple Facebook EdgeRank updates have penalized blatant advertisers & linkbait publishers like Upworthy, making it more difficult for many brand pages to get organic distribution. And it appears it will soon get [even more difficult](http://valleywag.gawker.com/facebook-is-about-to-make-everyone-pay-1547309811) to achieve organic reach, especially for "brand" pages.

How does Facebook determine what pages are owned by brands, and which are owned by publishers of substantive content. Are pages manually reviewed and added to a whitelist? Or is it all algorithmically determined.

And is there anything a page manager can do to ensure his/her posts are viewed by Facebook as content and not an ad?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently seeing more web pages in my Facebook feed that are shared by friends and fewer links shared by Facebook pages that I follow.  This makes me believe that to get reach on Facebook, you now need to get users to share your content, rather than trying to share it yourself through your Facebook page.

I'm also noticing that when I do share from my Faceook pages, I get better organic reach without links or images.   For example I have a page for a band that I play in.  When I announce our next concert on FB, I now post the venue and time information to the page without a link to the page about it on our site.   This seems to get the content in front of more of my followers.

So to demonstrate you have content:

- Get users to share it for you
- Post the content directly to Facebook rather than posting links to the content